# Is there an easier way to distress graphics in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

Recently I've been getting a lot of work with T-shirts and they ask me to distress t-shirts. This is a simple matter if the graphic is only one color, but occasionally I will get a graphic that's 4 or more colors and layered on top of each other. I will then have to apply a distressed texture to each separate shape. This can get tedious and time consuming. Not to mention the texture file is huge because it's distressed and creates a lot of points.

Do you guys know of a way that I can place a distressed texture on top of a vector graphic with multiple colors and shapes and just punch through or knockout all the way to the back of the stack? I hope that makes sense.

Here is an example.

[image: example]

There is white around the letters and the filled in areas on the face are white as well. I want the distressed graphic to punch through all the way, but when I use the minus front, it ends up only punching through some shapes or it all fuses together as one big mess.

If it helps the t-shirts will be screen printed.

Edit - Thanks for the answer, it works. Here is a rundown of how I created it [image: this]

Copied the graphic, and fused everything together as one solid shape. Placed distressed graphic over solid shape graphic. Create clipping mask of that. Place that over the original with the option clip checked.

Comment: An **Opacity Mask** is what you want. Check the duplicate link above your question. Feel free to click the "flag" link and ask a moderator to reopen if that duplicate isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a duplicate as it doesn't quite address the OP's question (which appears wanting to keep it pure solid vectors).

Comment: ...that said, The easiest way is to not bother keeping it vector. Open the vector illustration in something like Photoshop and then apply some textures there--or even easier, use a distressing plugin like the Mister Retro products http://www.misterretro.com/filters/machine-wash-deluxe/about

Comment: @DA01 opacity masks can be **100% vector**. (as shown in the video at the duplicate) Don't let the word "mask" make you think it has to be raster related. It *can* be raster, but it's not required.

Comment: @Scot I guess I don't know if that'd work for the oP or not. Seems like if he wants it to 'punch all the way through' there's no need for a mask (solid white on top would accomplish the same). We'd have to have the OP clarify.

Comment: What i'm worried about is if using opacity mask will cause problems screen printing.

Comment: No. The opacity mask is a mask. Upon output it simply hides the areas it masks. Should be zero issue outputting. But as @DA01 points out, for print, white objects on top would basically do the same thing. The mask is only helpful when combining files over various backgrounds. or when transparency is needed.

Comment: If it's a partial opacity mask, then that part of the screen print would end up having to be a half tone, which may or may not be an issue depending on how the screens are being made. You'd have to ask your printer.

Comment: I've reopened, but I still feel it's close to a duplicate of this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/opacity-mask-with-multiple-images-illustrator-cs5

Comment: Finally, another way to achieve the distress is to do it analog. If they're burning screens via laser prints, for instance, take the laser print, and crumple it up and uncrumple a bunch of times before using it to burn the screen. Sometimes the analog distressing is the best looking (and is also a lot more fun to create).

Comment: I really need it to be punched out. Opacity Mask work for showing how I want it to look, but I want the background, ie the shirt color to show through the t-shirt design.

Comment: Opacity masks will do that. If you use vector objects as the mask, it's a one or two click processes essentially. And leaves **all** the original art unaltered.

Comment: Maybe im not explaining it right. OK, here is a mockup in photoshop. I used opacity mask to create this by creating a large shape to cover the image and masking that out with the distressed vector. 

![example](http://i.gyazo.com/b29e75d56432f1e9b9e721482169b9e7.jpg)

See how it doesn't show through to the shirt, it's just putting white on top of the design. 

This is fine for presentation purposes, but when I hand this to a printer, I need to know that the white will not be there but substract from the design, because there are other areas of white that need to be kept.

Comment: The mask isn't configured correctly. That white should be hidden, unless it was not part of the masked artwork. See my answer below... the magenta shows through.

Comment: a bit late to this question, but if you're still around you could mark the answer as accepted since it solved your problem. Please check [ask] and the [tour]...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think **Opacity Masks** are the easiest here.

[image: set up]

[image: outline]

They are essentially a **one-click** method which is **non-destructive**. If you use 100% solid vector objects for the mask, then there's no concern about half toning either and the mask is just as infinitely scalable as the artwork under it. In addition, this method allows the mask artwork to be scaled, rotated, or changed *separately* from the underlying artwork. Being non-destructive, there's never a need to "start over". You can always adjust the texture *or* the artwork without a problem.

*Masked artwork needs to be one object (group) for best results.*

In many cases this method can increase the work speed in Illustrator compared to using Minus Front on each and every object. In addition, the mask tends to be faster with screen redraw as opposed to all the tiny objects Minus Front creates.

You could always expand and flatten the artwork after applying the mask to "bake in" the distressing (which is what Minus Front does).

Comment: Thank you!, I forgot to tick the clip box! It's resolved.!!!!!

Comment: The "Clip" and "Invert" options are on an as-needed basis. Those depend upon the artwork and the mask being used. Sometimes they are needed, sometimes not.

Comment: Here is proof that it works for anyone that is interested. 

[proof](http://i.gyazo.com/5d3ce5e350b4f5c232632648e58a2eeb.png)