# Punching out a shape and text in a complicated shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I am trying to recreate a logo in Illustrator that I made in Photoshop. I am not very experienced with Illustrator. In Photoshop, I used masking to mask out the shape of the treble clef and outline the text in the paint blob shape so those areas are actually transparent. Here is my image from Photoshop.

[image]

However I'm having trouble achieving the same effect in Illustrator. I have my paint blob, text and treble clef shapes. But I can't figure out how to create the transparent areas. Pathfinding is not working - when I create a compound shape I lose the three separate colours and end up with the entire blob in a single shape and colour.

Any ideas for how to go about this? Also, I can't figure out how to expand the text to get the perfect border like I could in Photoshop (in PS I simply selected the text and used Expand Selection).

Here's a screenshot of what I have in Illustrator.
[image]

After using pathfinder:
[image]

Comment: You need an **Opacity Mask** not a clipping mask. This may be helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/opacity-mask-with-multiple-images-illustrator-cs5

Answer (score 3):

You need an **Opacity Mask** in Illustrator. Clipping masks and/or Pathfinder aren't going to work, at least not easily.

Place the shape (type) you want to mask and the object(s) being masked on the same layer.

[image]

Select the mask shape and what you want masked:

[image]

Click the `Make Mask` button on the **Transparency Panel**.

[image]

Everything is going to disappear for a moment.
Click the `Clip` checkbox on the **Transparency Panel** and you should see the mask working as expected:

[image]

***Here, you're done.***

You'll notice the mask shape has vanished from the Layers Panel:

[image]

If you want to further edit the mask shape in the future, you need to click the mask thumbnail on the **Transparency Panel** to edit the mask.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Scott! That is amazingly helpful.
For the stroke on the text, I actually want that to be transparent as well like the treble clef shape. Any ideas on how to go about that?