# Illustrator: Logo fade out to transparency gradient in outer edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transparency, gradient

So, I've got a rectangular little/logo banner thing drawn up in Adobe Illustrator:

[image]

---

And I want to fade out to nothing around the edges relative to a new shape; in this case, an ellipse.

[image]

---

Here it is again with the fading part overlaid in pink for clarity. So it's like a frame within a frame.

[image]

---

Using a raster image editor, I managed to hack together an approximation of what I'm going for.

[image]

Comment: Huh? Not sure I get it. You will need an **Opacity Mask** to fade softly to transparency [SEE HERE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/opacity-mask-with-multiple-images-illustrator-cs5), which is generally a *bad* idea for a logo. Clipping masks will not "fade softly".

Comment: @Scott What don't you get? It's not complicated. The pink overlay represents the fade. The fade begins where the pink meets the black. So it's like.. cropping the corners but the edges bleed out.

Comment: I don't "get" .. what is to fade. A logo or that black ellipse?? Is type supposed to be hidden by the fade?

Answer (score 2):

### Rectangle

- Fill = none
- Stroke = Black
- Opacity = 100%

### Ellipse

- Fill = none
- Stroke = Black
- Opacity = 0%

### Blend

- Select both shapes
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps** > Increase the number

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the edit. Much Clearer (and easier to accomplish) than it appeared initially.

All you need is an ellipses with a soft edge. That can be accomplished a couple ways:

### 1.) The Feather Effect

Draw the ellipse and merely choose `Effect > Stylize > Feather` and enter a value. The higher the value the more the edge will blur. This blends *inward* from the edge of the ellipse.

[image]

or....

### 2). A Gradient

Draw the ellipse and fill it with a black to black **radial gradient**. Yes, set both color stops to the same color. However, set one color stop's **opacity** to 0%.

[image]

Switch to the **Gradient Tool** and using the on screen **Gradient Annotator** you can alter the gradient to match the shape of the ellipse, control where the drop off occurs, etc. This method gives more "live" control.

[image]

<sub>For an actual *logo* using soft edges, such as this, is generally a *bad* idea. But I don't know the actual implementation you may be envisioning.</sub>

Comment: Right, so I have the rectangular graphic. And now I have an ellipse. What's next? Do I use it to make a clipping mask or something? I mean, I can make an ellipse, no problems. It's the subtractive part that's tricky. Or are you saying I should just start from scratch?

Comment: @tjt263 That's the part you haven't *really* explained in the question. Is the rectangle something more than merely a color? Why do you even need the rectangle at all??

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you, man. Start with this, end with that. I like your diagrams and animations though.

Comment: Okay, well if you can't explain I surely can't assist. Good luck! I hope you get it figured out.

Comment: I've explained it. I've illustrated it. We've discussed it. There's not much else I can tell you. You get it right?

Comment: Uhm.. apparently not `:)`.  There's no explanation as to *why the rectangle is needed* at all. If the type content is NOT being masked then just delete the rectangle and draw a gradient-filled ellipse behind the type.

Comment: No, you're right. I only included details pertaining to the question. I appreciate you're trying to help, but 'm not looking for recommendations or advice on how best to approach things in a broad sense. I'm looking for specific instructions on how to do a certain thing a particular way. I really doubt you'd be satisfied with my reasoning anyway, even if I could articulate it. But in short, it's an artistic decision and it's conducive to my workflow. This is just a minimal, working example. It's not always going to be as simple as two basic monotone shapes.